# Is my Asus router capable of providing network bridging/WDS?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, asus

I want my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B to connect to the internet on a consistent basis, but its internal Wi-Fi module seems to work inconsistently at best, and my router is too far away to try to connect the two via ethernet cable.

My network topology is simple. My main router is an Asus RT-AX86U. My phones, computers, and other media devices connect just fine with the network. I cannot recall any problems connecting those devices to the network.

The one computer that has had trouble connecting to the network is the Pi. My typical experience connecting it via Wi-Fi is that it works fine at first then falls to getting something on the order of a handful of a few Kbps in speed (whereas I consistently get 300+ Mbps on every other device).

I have chalked this to the Pi's Wi-Fi module just being bad. I think this has been the case since the first Wi-Fi-enabled model came out, and everything I have seen so far suggests that is the case with this device.

I'm not trying to solve any problem worth a great monetary investment by connecting the Pi to the internet, so I tried a cheap solution at first and am steadily trying more expensive solutions. I'm hoping to stop before I have to spend ~$100.

My first attempt was installing a TP-Link USB Wi-Fi adapter ([model N150](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008IFXQFU)). I don't remember the details of that experience, but basically, it didn't work. I think the Pi could recognize the device, but my attempts at disabling the internal Wi-Fi module to make the thing prefer the external module failed.

My second attempt was to buy a cheap TP-Link router ([model TL-WA801N](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09JZPXSBJ)) and set the router up as a Wi-Fi client to my Asus router. I figured if the configuration was happening solely within the router and outside the Pi, I would have better luck.

The TP-Link router never successfully connected to my Asus router, making me believe that perhaps the two models were incompatible when trying to use one in bridge or client mode. I nearly tried installing DD-WRT but could not find evidence that would work with the version (6.8) I had.

My third and current attempt was to buy a slightly nicer router to put into client mode: [the GL.iNet AR300M16-Ext](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07794JRC5). I connected the router via the LAN port to my Pi, went to the adminisration portal, entered the PSK for my Asus Wi-Fi network, and got a failure message. I've tried a few things but have only gotten as far as getting the Pi a bad IP address (169.254.28.196) and have never seen the Asus list the Pi or the GL.iNet router as a client.

Here is an assortment of solutions I have tried with each of the three devices:

- Turn everything off and on again
- Disable [Smart Connect](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/asus-smart-connect/) on the Asus router
- Enable and connect to a single-band guest network (mostly to avoid messing with the main network, thereby interrupting my other devices)
- Add the MAC of the client device (second router) to the Remote AP List under Wireless > WDS in the Asus router's configuration

What else can I try? What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: The typical reason for poor RPi wifi is that power saving is set to enabled. `iwconfig wlan0 power off` if I remember correctly should work. If it works, set it as default.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a used AC68U or AC86U & use them as the wireless bridge. I get near gigabit speeds up & down on the 5ghz connection from the computer i'm on right now connected via cat5e to the lan port on an ac68u on my shelf, which connects wirelessly to an AX86u downstairs in another room & the speeds are fantastic. I was very very very pleasantly surprised when I saw how much faster it was than trying to use either a PCI-E wireless card or a USB wifi adapter.

If you stick with Asus routers, at least the AC series or better I'm pretty sure the WDS bridge is very high in inter-device compatibility across most of their product line. You can get a used AC68U on ebay for around $30